# Dual select menu in one cell JqGrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid, html-select

I want to display two select boxes in one cell or separate cells merged into one. As the grid requires two values displayed in one cell and those values when edited becomes two different select menus each getting their values from the arrays.

I have setup a example code on which I want to achieve this. This code contains two arrays `arr1` and `arr2`. I want the data of these two arrays to be displayed in select menus aligned like they are aligned at the top (in that html table) in one cell and each select contains an array as select options.

**Code**: **[jsFiddle code](http://jsfiddle.net/049v68cc/)**

Is it doable..? I am using JQgrid 4.6.0.

```js
var data = [
  [48803, "AAF1", "", "02200220", "OPEN", "D,AB", "D,AC", "E,AD", "F,AE", "D,AD"],
  [48769, "AAD33", "", "77733337", "OPEN", "D,AB", "D,AB", "E,AD", "F,AD", "D,AB"]

];

var op1 = {
  value: '1:D; 2:E; 3:F'
};
var op2 = {
  value: '1:AB;2:AC; 3:AD; 4:AE'
};

var arr1 = ["D", "E", "F"];
var arr2 = ["AB", "AC", "AD", "AE"];


$("#grid").jqGrid({
  datatype: "local",
  height: 250,
  colNames: ['ID', 'CPR', 'Blank', 'DeptID', 'Status', '01', '02', '03', '04', '05'],
  colModel: [{
    name: 'ID',
    index: 'ID',
    width: 50,
    sorttype: "int"
  }, {
    name: 'CPR',
    index: 'CPR',
    editable: true,
    width: 60,
    sorttype: "date"
  }, {
    name: 'blank',
    editable: true,
    index: 'blank',
    width: 10
  }, {
    name: 'DeptID',
    index: 'DeptID',
    editable: true,
    width: 60,
    sorttype: "float"
  }, {
    name: 'Status',
    index: 'Status',
    width: 60,
    sorttype: "float"
  }, {
    name: '01',
    index: '01',
    editable: true,
    edittype: "select",
    formatter: myformatter,
    editoptions: op2,
    width: 30,
  }, {
    name: '02',
    index: '02',
    editable: true,
    edittype: "select",
    formatter: myformatter,
    editoptions: op1,
    width: 30,
  }, {
    name: '03',
    index: '03',
    editable: true,
    edittype: "select",
    formatter: myformatter,
    editoptions: op1,
    width: 30,
  }, {
    name: '04',
    index: '04',
    editable: true,
    edittype: "select",
    formatter: myformatter,
    editoptions: op1,
    width: 30,
  }, {
    name: '05',
    index: '05',
    editable: true,
    edittype: "select",
    formatter: myformatter,
    editoptions: op1,
    width: 30,
  }, ],
  'cellEdit': true,
  caption: "Stack Overflow Example",
  // ondblClickRow: function(rowid,iRow,iCol,e){alert('double clicked');}
});

var names = ['ID', 'CPR', 'Blank', 'DeptID', 'Status', '01', '02', '03', '04', '05'];
var mydata = [];

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  mydata[i] = {};
  for (var j = 0; j < data[i].length; j++) {
    mydata[i][names[j]] = data[i][j];
  }
}

for (var i = 0; i <= mydata.length; i++) {
  $("#grid").jqGrid('addRowData', i + 1, mydata[i]);
}

function myformatter(cellvalue, options, rowObject) {
  var array = cellvalue.split(",");
  return array[0] + " " + array[1];
}
```

```html
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.14/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/themes/ui.jqgrid.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/js/i18n/grid.locale-en.js"></script>
<script src="http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/js/jquery.jqGrid.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <select>
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <select>
        <option>3</option>
        <option>4</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<table id="grid"></table>
```

**Update:**
Tony's suggestion worked. I have created a new fiddle which contains two select menus when the cell is edited.

**JSFiddle: [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/5voc8tc0/)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently the one way to realize this is to use custom edit type.

In this custom edit type you will need to create the two selects using the custom_element property and get and set the value using the custom_value property.

See [here](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:common_rules#edittype) for more information (scroll to the end to see the custom element). You will see a example how to use the custom element.

I’m not sure that cellEdit is a good option for this. Maybe you can try with inline or form edit options.

Best Regards,

Comment: Thanks @TonyTomov it worked. :) Example for someone needing help:
**[Link to Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5voc8tc0/)**